# Does a closed walk necessarily contain a cycle?

Tags: graph-theory

[HOMEWORK]

I asked my professor and he said that a counter example would be two nodes, by which the pathw ould go from one node and back. this would be a closed path but does not contain a cycle. But I am confused after looking at this again. Why is this not a cycle? Need there be another node?

Comment: This may depend on your local definitions of walk, path, cycle.

Comment: A walk that contains each vertex at most once, is called a cycle if tis closed and the start and end point are equal. Path being the same, only open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the answer depends on the exact definition of cycle. If it is as you wrote in your comment - a closed walk that starts and ends in the same vertex, and no vertex repeats on the walk (except for the start and end), then your example with two nodes is a cycle.

However, a definition of a cycle usually contains a condition of non-triviality stating that a cycle has at least three vertices. So a graph with two vertices is not a cycle according to this definition.

Comment: as I suspected, mostly by geometric interpretation of a cycle not being the same as line..